# Construction a multiplicative inverse of a real number via Dedekind cuts

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I'm reading Pugh's "Real Mathematical Analysis" where C.Pugh constructs real numbers system using Dedekind cuts. Unfortunately, he omits a construction of a multiplicative inverse of a real number $x = A|B$ where $A$ and $B$ are cuts in $\mathbb{Q}$. First, some required definitions:

> A cut in $\mathbb{Q}$ is a pair of subsets $A,B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that
>
> a)$A \cup B = \mathbb{Q}, A \neq  \varnothing, B \neq \varnothing, A \cap B = \varnothing$
>
> b) If $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ then $a < b$
>
> c) A contains no largest element
>
> A real number is a cut in $\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> The additive inverse of a cut $x = A|B$ is defined as $(-x) = C|D$ where $C = \{r \in Q| \exists b \in B$ (not the smallest elements of $B$ ) $: r = -b \}$ and $D = \mathbb{Q} \setminus C$
>
> Multiplication is defined for positive numbers $x > 0$. If $x = A|B, y = C|D$, then $xy = E|F$ where
>
> $E = \{r \in \mathbb{Q}| r \leq 0$ or $\exists a \in A \ \ \exists c \in C: a > 0, c > 0, r = ac \}, F = \mathbb{Q} \setminus E$. If $x > 0, y < 0$ then we define $xy = -(x(-y))$

Now I wonder how can we define a multiplicative inverse of a positive cut $x = A|B$. Obviously, it's a cut $\frac{1}{x} = C|D$ such that $x \frac{1}{x} = 1$

So, it's such a cut $C|D$ such that for $C$ we have
$\{r \in \mathbb{Q}| r \leq 0$ or $\exists a \in A \ \ \exists c \in C : a > 0, b > 0, r = ac \} = \{r \in \mathbb{Q}| r < 1 \}$

Any ideas how we can define $C$(if we define $C$, then $D = \mathbb{Q} \setminus C$)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Changed to correct the error modnar points out in the comments.

If $x > 0$, $$C = \{r \in \Bbb Q \mid \exists b \in B,\, rb < 1\}$$
If $x < 0$, $$C = \{r \in \Bbb Q \mid \exists b \in B,\, b < 0\text{ and } rb > 1\}$$

---

Original post: (has maximums when $x$ is rational)

If $x > 0$, $$C = \{ r \in \Bbb Q \mid r \le 0 \text{ or } \forall a \in A,\, ra < 1\}$$

If $x < 0$, $$C = \{ r \in \Bbb Q \mid \forall a \in A, \,ra > 1\}$$

Comment: When $a$ is the multiplicative identity in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e, $a=\{r\in \mathbb{Q}\mid r<1\}$, the above $C$ becomes $a\cup \{1\}$, which has a greatest element $1$.

Comment: @modnar - it took a while to interpret your comment, because the first time you mentioned "$a$", you actually meant "$x$", and the other two times you mentioned "$a$", you actually meant "$A$". However, you are correct, and the problem is not just with $1$, but occurs any time $x$ is rational. I've changed the answer to one version that doesn't have maximums. A different fix would have been to just add $r \ne \min B$ to each of the original set definitions, but then I'd have to point out this still works when $\min B$ doesn't exist.

Comment: You are right. The notation in my comment is confusing. I like your revised construction, which is quite elegant.

Comment: I am confused. Why did you not simply take $C=\{\frac{1}{y}:x\ne y\in B\}$?

Comment: @Shahab - when $x < 0$, your $C$ will contain both positive elements that are $> \frac 1x$ and negative elements that are $< \frac 1x$. When $x > 0$,  your $C$ will not contain $0$ itself, which the full lower Dedekind cut should include. And even for non-zero rationals, my version obviously contains every rational $<\frac 1x$, while yours requires an additional (though simple) argument to show it. And another reason is that my version doesn't require the development of division in $\Bbb Q$ before it can be introduced.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: I suppose we can prove that the inverse and $x$, multiply to $1$, using the fact that $a/[a+1/n]$ approaches $1$, and we can find such $a$ in $x$ such that $a+1/n$ is in its inverse. Does that work?

Comment: @VoiletFlame - why go to all that trouble? Suppose $x > 0$, and pretend the negatives do not exist. $C = \{r\mid \forall a \in A, ra < 1\}$ and $E = \{ac\mid a \in A, c \in C\}$. So we see that for all $e \in E, e < 1$. Conversely, if $e \in \Bbb Q_+ < 1$ and $a > 0 \in A$, then $c = \frac ea \in \Bbb Q_+$ and $ca = e < 1$, so $c \in C$ and $ac = e \in E$. Thus $E = \{r \in \Bbb Q_+ | r < 1\}$, which means $E|F = 1$ in the reals. I'll leave how to modify the argument to include the negatives, and the corresponding argument when $x < 0$ to you.

Comment: Sorry my def of an inverse is a bit different page 15 here http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~krapp/research/Constructions_of_the_real_numbers.pdf , how to prove it from that def? Thank you for the kind response. Specifically in my definition there must exist a point $p$ in the complement such that $pq<1$ and then we union off $0$ and the negative rationals.

Comment: I guess I don’t understand the definition of $C$ according to the top of your post it should be different no?

Comment: The book of landau gives a similar solution to mine, could you please clarify?

Comment: I suppose I would want a solution that uses the def in the article I gave, or one that uses the definition in the top of the post. The solution you gave uses the bottom def, if I’m not mistaken. thanks!

Comment: This is not the right place to ask questions about other definitions and approaches. To ask such questions, start your own thread about them. These are the comments on my answer here, and should only be used to address that answer.  As for the definition of $C$ in my comment, I pointed out right at the start that I was going to ignore negatives, and left the matter of adjusting to include negatives to you. The negatives here (for $x > 0$ case) are just a technical addendum to both $C$ and $E$. The important action is on the positive side.

Comment: But do you agree that according to the def I’m using (the one given in the pdf) my proof is the way to go? I apologise for deviating and thank you for your kind responses.

Comment: I just said questions not **directly** relatd to this post need to be asked in their own thread. I meant it. There are several very strong reasons for this rule. I will not break it for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134642/discussion-between-voilet-flame-and-paul-sinclair).I think we can discuss this in chat?Please let me know in chat if you’d like to discuss this further. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A possible way to fix the bug mentioned under Paul's answer is
$$C=\{r\in \mathbb{Q}\mid r\leq 0\ \text{or}\ (\exists s\in \mathbb{Q}\ (r<s)\ \text{and}\ (\forall a\in A\ sa<1))\}$$
for the case $x>0$. A similar trick should be able to take care of the case $x<0$, too.

Comment: If you properly qualify $a$, that will work. As is, $C = \emptyset$, since for any rational $s$, there are *objects* $a$ for which multiplication with $s$ is defined and $sa > 1$.

Comment: @Paul, Indeed. $\forall a$ should be $\forall a\in A$. Thanks.